# Change hibernation time when on a known/domain network

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate

For our laptop users, I would like to have their laptops hibernate after 65 minutes when working remotely (On an unknown network/home network), however when working on the domain or a known IP address I would like to diable hibernation.

Is this possible somehow?

Laptops are running WIndows 7 Enteprise 32 bit and being amanged on a Windows SErver 2008 R2 domain and also using SCCM 2012.

Answer (score 0):

There are no Group Policy Power Configuration Settings available natively to configure Hibernation for domain members. However you can create a settings that can be applied to all computers on the domain (yes not exactly what you are asking for):

You must use a custom ADM file or a small script which can be executed from a remote computer to enable hibernation. The tool name is PowerCFG.exe. This can be used to enable hibernation but there is no remote support available with this tool. You might need to use a tool which can execute the command on remote computers to enable hibernation. We will be using Psexec.exe to execute Powercfg.exe remotely.

Steps:

Create a text file; Comps.txt
Put all the computer names in it.
Next, copy the following lines in a file and save it as EnableH.CMD

```
REM ***START HERE***
Echo Off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%L IN (Comps.txt) DO (
   SET CompName=
   SET CompName=%%L
   psexec.exe \\!CompName! C:\Windows\System32\Powercfg.exe /hibernate ON
)
REM ***END HERE***
```

You can download the Psexec.exe from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

The only way that you could get closer to your goal would be to apply this on logon and a different settings at logoff but I would not recommend that as it is not practical and most users don;t logoff these days anyway - they simply hibernate or put the computer to sleep :-)

Your best bet is to set the best setting that works on and outside of the domain